# Two UIButtons sharing code

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have a `UICollectionView` with 4 custom cells.  cells 0 and 3 are identical in design.  However, the code case is almost identical to the functions and objects.  Both have 3 identical `UIButtons`, lets say one set is for player 1 and the other for player 2.  I don't want to copy the code and have it duplicated from the buttons in cell 0.  What's the best (I know that's subjective) to have all the buttons using the same code base?  I thought to place a tag on the button so I know what button is calling.

Or is this a job for generics?

```
@IBAction func undo(_ sender: UIButton) {

    undo(sender: sender)

}

func undo(sender: sender) {

     if sender.tag = 0 {

          // Do something that is different for button 0

     } else if sender.tag = 1 {

        // Do something that is different for button 1

     }

     //Common to all buttons...

}
```

Comment: If your code is just using different data, you can build a function that receives the *data*.  Then your button handlers just call that function with the data to use.

Comment: Definitely not generics. Using tags is a bad practice. From your example is not very clear what is common.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little tough to fully understand what you are trying to do, but it sounds like you may want to is inject a closure into your cell (or ideally some kind of view model for the cell) which has the behavior you want to execute already defined, and call it when the cell is tapped.